# Padding arrays in C++ without translating indices

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, syntax, padding

Here is what I have:

```
int t[MX];
```

Now, I'd like to rewrite that code so as to effectively add a single element to the beginning of that array, without having to translate all of the indexing by 1 in the rest of the code. A solution to that problem might be something like this:

```
int _t[MX+1];
int * const t = _t+1;
```

The problem with this approach is that now something like this doesn't work anymore:

```
memset(t, 0, sizeof t);
```

The problem is that `sizeof t` returns 4, instead of MX*4 as I'd want it to.

One possible solution might be:

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b[MX];
} _t;
int (&t)[MX] = _t.b;
```

But I find it rather inelegant and unsatisfactory.
So, my question would be:
Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you use that over an `std::vector` ?

Comment: I don't want to rewrite anything other than that small part of the code. I'd like to keep the code as simple as possible, not introduce some heavy classes like that. Anyway, I don't really see how would that help.

Comment: then you should have tagged it as 'c' - there's not much c++ here. BTW, how is `std::vector` heavy?

Comment: @user2081465 learn the containers of the standard C++ library.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic `int (&t)[MX] = _t.b;` I believe would not be possible in C since this is a reference.
I want the solution to be as simple, short and efficient as possible, that is why I do not want to use stl.

Comment: that's exactly why I wrote `there's not much c++` instead of `there's no c++` - that part is not essential to the described problem, it could have been a pointer as well, as pointers can be used with array syntax

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Well, I could have written `int (*t)[MX] = &_t.b;`, but then I would have to rewrite the rest of the code from something like `t[i]` to `(*t)[i]`, which is something I said I do not want to do. The only part that can be changed is the declaration, therefore it is essential. Unless you had something else in mind?

Comment: or just `int* t = &_t.b;` and then `t[i]`?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Then I would lose the ability to use `sizeof` operator.

Comment: ah, I see. but still the whole idea seems strange to me - `memset` will now only rewrite a part of array and leave the first element with different value. is that desired?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Yes, that would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is the second solution "inelegant and unsatisfactory", it is also undefined behavior. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4006736/335858) for more information on the topic.

The first solution lets you work with negative indexes, because `ptr[index]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + index)`, so as long as the result points to within the array, you will be fine.

A solution to `sizeof` problem could be built by following the approach taken by the designers of [`std::array<T,size_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array): make a template class that wraps an array, and do your index translation inside its subscript operator.

If this does not work, you can go back to a combination of your original two solutions, but without undefined behavior, like this:

```
#define MX 1000

typedef int arr_mx[MX];

int _t[MX+1];
arr_mx &t = *((arr_mx*)(&_t[1]));
```

Here is a [demo of this approach on ideone](http://ideone.com/LDlsWQ).

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I also had to implement a conversion operator to `int*` to make it fully compatible with the existing code. This way it works ok with `memset`, it'll just set all the values to whatever, including the one with "index" -1. The problem is that the conversion to `int*` must return pointer to the element -1, otherwise `memset` will try to set the value of the first element after last because the `sizeof` operator, which is not overloadable, has to return the size of the whole object. Now, functions that expect to get pointer to the element 0 of my array, will be getting -1.

Comment: @toi333 The operator `int*` should be returning the untranslated address. Only the operator `int& []` should be returning the translated one. This way your `memset` would be able to fill the buffer with zeros without getting past the end of the buffer. Functions that need the translated pointer should use `&t[0]` instead of `(int*)t` to get the translated address.

Comment: That's how I implemented it. Unfortunately, what you're suggesting at the end, I cannot do because that would require rewriting other parts of the code. `t` alone should be implicitly castable to `int*` to element 0 (index 1 in the actual array).

Comment: Very nice, that is perfect! Thanks a lot!